# How to produce a Linux-like `ls` output in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, ls

I don't want the output of `ls`(`Get-ChildItem`) to be **vertical** (one file one line) in Powershell. I want it to be **horizontal** (like a table in Linux). After searching the web I don't know how to do that.

And `ls -n | Format-Table` doesn't work. It's  still vertical.

I'm not a native English speaker, so forgive me for some grammar mistakes.

Comment: Not an answer to your question directly, but if you wish to have `ls` styled directory output, there are ports of `ls` for Windows which do not require PowerShell, which you may want to consider.

Comment: I think I know what you want. You just want file names tab separated?

Comment: I cheat and use scoop. This will not give you items in the object level gci would, however it adds many of your favourite *nix tools to windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not really sure why you'd want to do this on Windows or expect a Linux file system listing on Windows. Yet, but this is about a close as you will get, with Windows PowerShell natively.

```
#Collect the path listing, split on the line feed, join with a space delimiter 
(ls -n) -split "`n" -join " "
```

The Windows file system just does not natively list files this way by design,  and Windows PowerShell's goal is not to mimic what other OS's file systems do.  Windows file system will use its native a single string list, by design and not the table-like view in *NIX. No color highlighting of file or directories either.

Before you ask, no, you cannot just use Format-Table to what I am showing. If you want this look, then you need to write your own wrapper for LS/GCI or Use PoSHv6 on *NIX or OSX, or use a 'ls' port as noted by the other response or if you are on Win10, enable WSL (Bash on Linux) and just use WSL instead of Win PoSH.

You can of course only select file or directory list as well.

```
(ls -n -directory) -split "`n" -join " "

(ls -n -file) -split "`n" -join " "
```

You can use the Format-Wide cmdlet, depending on what PoSH version you are on.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-wide?view=powershell-6

```
ls | Format-Wide -Column 5
```

But what you cannot do  is...

```
ls -n | Format-Wide -Column 5
```

...it will fail, no workaround that way.

You have to do stuff like this... work.

```
ls | Format-Wide -Column 5 -Property Name
```

... since it is the Format-Wide cmdlet doing this

Comment: Downvoted because the "why try to imitate Linux" part of the answer is unnecessary. OP's question was clearly about getting a more compact formatting of the output.

Comment: Just because your answer was technically useful doesn't mean the sass was necessary, hence @jmlorenzi 's highly-upvoted comment. I came across this question because I'm trying to do a "quick" directory listing to get a large list of filenames and then move on. The "lazy equivalent" for me in Unix would be `ls *.yaml` ; but the way to do this in PowerShell isn't obvious.

Comment: _The Windows file system just does not natively list files_ Filesystem lists files? That should be a surprise to anyone who understands what a filesystem is. What is **The Windows file system** anyways?

Answer (score 13):

If you have Windows Subsystem for Linux installed (WSL) you can call `ls` directly.

Typing

```
wsl ls
```

Actually calls the linux ls command and gives you the same output you'd find on linux.

You can update the "ls" alias so it always call this using Powershells "Set-Alias". In the Powershell profile file (Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) do:

```
function ls_alias { wsl ls --color=auto -hF $args }
Set-Alias -Name ls -Value ls_alias -Option AllScope
```

That also allows you to pass in additional parameters, for instance show all files with:

```
ls -a
```

Note though: You'll have to pass in a Unix style path, not a windows one or it will not be recognised. For instance, this:

```
ls /mnt/c/tmp/my_file
```

but not:

```
ls C:\tmp\my_file
```

Comment: And how is it relevant to PowerShell?

Comment: @ﾤﾡ "How is it relevant to PowerShell?" You type it in PowerShell of course...(?!)

Comment: What WSL has to do with PowerShell?

Answer (score 5):

Try this command:

```
Get-ChildItem $args -Exclude .*  | Format-Wide Name -AutoSize
```

and you can always add an alias in the Powershell profile file (Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1):

```
function l { Get-ChildItem $args -Exclude .*  | Format-Wide Name -AutoSize }
```

Or if you want to see the hidden files too:

```
Get-ChildItem $args -Force | Format-Wide Name -AutoSize
```

If you are wondering what is happening here, these are base Powershell commands. `Get-ChildItem` is the base command for `dir` and `ls`. `Format-Wide` takes a list and formats it.

Comment: With aliases you can shorten this to `ls -dir | fw Name -a` or even `ls -dir | fw -a`

Answer (score 4):

If you have git installed (and we all do, right?), you can use the `ls` that's bundled with git. Benefits are that it's a fast native binary and works with Windows path separators. Here's what it looks like:

[image: ls output like on Linux]

Put the following code in your PowerShell profile (its filepath is inside the `$profile` variable):

```
if ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    function ls_git { & 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls' --color=auto -hF $args }
    Set-Alias -Name ls -Value ls_git -Option Private
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a package a while back to do just this! You can read the installation instructions here: https://github.com/JRJurman/PowerLS

As far as how it works under the hood, there is some parsing of the the files and folders in the directory, and then it uses write-host with some color flags to generate a pretty nice output. Check the readme in the repo for examples.

Comment: It seem to have been relocated to [HERE](https://github.com/gardebring/PowerColorLS) now....

Answer (score 1):

`ls -e .* | fw Name -a`

`ls -e .* | fw Name -c 10` (more squished)

`ls` above is an *alias* for `Get-ChildItem`. `-e .*` excludes items beginning with '.' (similar to `ls`).

The output is then piped to `fw` (an alias for `Format-Wide`) which is taking the property `Name` from each directory object. The `-a` is to "AutoSize" the column count for more compact results.

If you still don't have it compact enough manually increase the column count using the `-c` option instead. It will truncate some names that do not fit but usually this is fine because it is a human who is reading it. For automation you would/should use `Get-ChildItem` like this: `Get-ChildItem | %{ Write-Host $_.Name "is a" $_.Attributes }`

When you find what you like add an `Alias` to your `$PROFILE`

Answer (score 0):

create a $profile variable with

```
New-Item $profile -Type File -Force
```

It creates a file called Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 in a folder called WindowsPowerShell under your Documents folder. Then you can open it with a text editor:

```
notepad $profile
```

add this to your $profile variable.

```
if ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    function ls_git { & 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls' --color=auto -hF $args }
    Set-Alias -Name ls -Value ls_git -Option AllScope
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to make this work, as I'm not much a PowerShell guru. Instead, I installed the 'lsd' package, which works identically on Linux and Windows. Add your LS_COLORS environment variable and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

## eza

The `eza` program aims to be an alternative to the `ls` command from coreutil with more features and sensible defaults.

[image: eza demonstration]

### Installing on Windows

With winget:
`winget install eza-community.eza`

With scoop:
`scoop install eza`

[The website](https://eza.rocks/) has additional information and documentation. Notably, shell completion.

Comment: Just two days after your post, exa was declared unmaintained as it's maintainer is unreachable. The community fork eza has windows support. Can be installed via `winget install eza-community.eza`.

Comment: @JoakimThorén Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly.