# Windows: How to create a tab-separated list of information about files in a directory

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems, batch-file, text-formatting

As a Linux user I have no idea to solve the following problem on Windows (using cmd.exe):

I want to list all files in a given directory recursively with the following information seperated by tabs into a file:

1. full path
2. full path w/o file name
3. file name
4. file suffix
5. timestamp of last change
6. user that touched the file recently

e.g.

`c:\folderA\file1.txt<tab>c:\folderA<tab>file1.txt<tab>txt<tab>2016-02-18 15:18:29 +0100<tab>USER_X`

`c:\folderA\file2.txt<tab>c:\folderA<tab>file2.txt<tab>txt<tab>2018-02-28 14:28:44 +0100<tab>USER_Y`

`c:\folderA\folderAA\file3.xlsx<tab>c:\folderA\folderAA<tab>file3.xlsx<tab>xslx<tab>2011-12-01 05:22:01 +0100<tab>USER_Z`

There might be files and folders with spaces in their names.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1325217/how-to-produce-a-linux-like-ls-output-in-powershell/1325363

Comment: You will struggle in `cmd`, you'd be better off using `powershell`

Comment: Thanks @spikey_richie, I'll try powershell...

Answer (score 1):

use **powershell** instead of **cmd** use powershell command `Get-ChildItem` alias `GCI`

**Full Command:**

```
gci -r | % { $_.Name,$_.FullName,$_.LastWriteTime -join ' ' } | Out-File YourOutputfile.txt
```

`gci` **Get-ChildItem**

`-r` **recursive**

`$_.Name` **File Name**

`$_.FullName` **File Full Path**

**same output:**

```
Get-ChildItem -r | % { $_.Name,$_.FullName,$_.LastWriteTime -join ' ' } | Out-File YourOutputfile.txt
```

If You still want to use `cmd` then type `for /?` hit enter and read this section

```
    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Comment: Thanks @Sadam! What about the file's owner (or user that touched the file recently)?